# Does tensorflow.python.lib.io.file_io allow setting MIME types?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-storage, mime-types

Can I set the MIME type of an object that I create in Google Cloud Storage with TensorFlow's `tensorflow.python.lib.io.file_io` to `text/plain`, as I could with `gsutil` e.g. like this:

```
 gsutil cp -h "Content-Type:text/plain" local_file gs://$BUCKET_NAME/dir
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can set MIME types in Cloud Storage using TensorFlow, but you can set the content type when you call the `upload_from_filename` function of the Google Cloud Storage Library. The documentation is [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html).